Создание модели ManyToMany с обязательным полем
Есть модельки Городов и Туров. Тур может проходить по нескольким городам, в городе может проходить несколько туров.
Логично - Many To Many.
Но городу никто не запрещает существовать без тура, а вот тур 100% должен проходить как миниму  по одному городу.
Т.е. при создании города я могу не указывать туры, а вот при создании тура я обязан указать город.
class Tour(UUIDMixin, NameMixin, Model):
    description = TextField(_('description'))
    cities = ManyToManyField(
        'City',
        verbose_name = _('cities'),
        through = 'TourCity'
    )

    def __str__(self) -> None:
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"tours_data"."tour"'
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = _('tour')
        verbose_name_plural = _('tours')
        unique_together = (('name', 'description', 'cities'),)

class City(UUIDMixin, NameMixin, Model):
    country = CharField(
        _('country'),
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        max_length=COUNTRY_MAX_LEN
    )

    def __str__(self) -> None:
        return f'{self.name}, {self.country}'

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"tours_data"."city"'
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = _('city')
        verbose_name_plural = _('cities')
        unique_together = (('name', 'country'),)

class TourCity(UUIDMixin, Model):
    tour = ForeignKey(Tour, verbose_name=_('tour'), on_delete=CASCADE)
    city = ForeignKey(City, verbose_name=_('city'), on_delete=CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"tours_data"."tour_city"'
        unique_together = (('tour', 'city'),)
        verbose_name = _('relationship tour city')
        verbose_name_plural = _('relationships tour city')

Однако я все еще могу создать тур и не добавить в него ни одного города. Как это можно исправить?

Ну сам подумай, как ты выполняешь эту операцию. Сначала ты создаёшь тур. Потом добавляешь в него города, один или несколько. Но между созданием и добавлением первого города присутствует время, когда у тура городов нет вообще. А потому существование тура без городов - это штатное событие. Либо следует принять, что (начальный) город - это обязательный атрибут тура, а не просто один из городов списка. И создать под него отдельное поле.

@Akina ок, я понял. Но я все равно не должен создавать тур без городов. Есть возможность как-то фильтравать это через форму? Как получить значение каждого extra?

Ну я ж предложил вариант - добавить в объект Тур обязательное поле НачальныйГород. Этот город ты просто обязан указать при создании тура - то есть если тур создан, в нём есть минимум один город НачальныйГород и, возможно, ещё несколько в списке городов тура. Хотя для единообразия обработки я бы автоматически добавлял этот НачальныйГород и в список, если его там ещё нет.

@Akina звучит как костыль

Как по мне, так это требование наличия города звучит неразумно. По-моему, достаточно при отсутствии городов просто ограничивать доступ к такому туру - пока нет ни одного города, тур можно только редактировать. Или удалить. Ну или как вариант - вообще не сохранять такой тур, считая его невалидным.

@Akina вот, я и хочу его не сохранять, но не очень охота делать отдельное поле для первого города.

Для проверки помогают инлайны.
Поле min_num просто не даст создать запись в таблице если не удет заполнен хотя бы один инлайн. Он проверяет не то что инлайн просто добавлен, но и что в нем хранится значение.
Есть еще max_num - но она не для моего случая, может кому понадобится.
Итак, в admin.py делаем инлайн:
class TourCityInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TourCity
    min_num = 1

Который в последствии применяем ко всем нужным классам в админ-панели:
@admin.register(Tour)
class TourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Tour
    inlines = (TourCityInline,)

